# How does `resolveAfter2Seconds ` return 20?

Tags: javascript

Below code is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.

I don't understand how can `resolveAfter2Seconds(20)` return `20` for variable a.

In my opinion, the only way to get the "return value" from a `resolved Promise` is to use `Promise.prototype.then()`. The code below doesn't use `then()` but still can get the `20`. Why? Am I missing something or missunderstanding something?

```
  function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
      });
    }

async function add1(x) {
  var a = resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + await a + await b;
}

add1(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 2 seconds.
});

async function add2(x) {
  var a = await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b;
}

add2(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 4 seconds.
});
```

Comment: resolve(x) where x is 20?

Comment: And *await* does the same as then... prom.then(v=>) === v=await prom;

Comment: `a` is not `20`. `await a` is `20`.

Comment: @Jonasw you are right, the await doc also mention that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Await returns resolved value

### But But

### Doesn't returns rejected value

for that we need to use `try-catch` block. you can refer the example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
 return new Promise(reject => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   reject(x);
  }, 2000);
 });
}

async function add1(x) {

 try {
  return await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
 } catch (e) {
  return e
 }

}

add1(10).then(v => {
 console.log(v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` will return the resolved value.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> If a Promise is passed to an await expression, it waits for the
>   Promise's resolution and returns the resolved value.